# Powerpoint table shading color does not match what I asked

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint

I am on macOs, with powerpoint 16.67

To reproduce:

- I started a new presentation
- Create a new table. Number of cells don't matter.
- Select layout and click "shading". I tried also with shape fill, but I get the same result
- Change the color to a given RGB value. In my case, 248, 237, 121.
- Open color picker and check the resulting color
- See image: the color does not match. I suspect there's something to do with color profiles, but selecting native, or any other selector, I am unable to get the exact values I specified. What's going on here?

[image]

Comment: I believe the Digital Colour Meter shows the values displayed on your screen -- these values may be different from the actual value depending on the colour profile used for the display -- I would trust the numbers in Powerpoint

Comment: Adding to @cybernetic.nomad's reply:  MacOS is color-managing the output to your monitor so that it matches the color you'll get on your output device (a printer usually).  This is high idiocy in a situation where the output device isn't known (or where there may BE no output device other than the monitor itself).  Apple seems to move the color management settings from place to place in each new version of MacOS; you'll want to look up how to disable color management for your particular MacOS version.